# Open selected folder in VS Code from the VS Code terminal (Windows 10)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been searching around and I can't find any way to open the selected folder in VS Code while using the VS Code terminal. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this would open in the same instance, but `code .` should open the current folder

Comment: Just gave me an error saying vscode wasn't valid. (with respect to the pre-edited answer, it suggested using "vscode .")

Comment: oh awesome! Thanks that worked. It does open in a new instance but that's ok for my workflow for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14):

Are you trying to open in the same VSCode instance to which the integrated terminal belongs?

Try:

```
code -r .
```

Answer (score 2):

from Terminal enter

```
code -r <folderPath>
```

this should open folder in vsCode
press CTRL + ~ if you are on windows to re-open terminal

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to open your folder in vscode from existing opened vscode terminal. It will not create new vscode tab. So you will not need to close second vscode. You will be only in one vscode.

```
code -r .
```

Enjoy `:)`