# Open VSCode using `code .` in the current window, instead of opening a new window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to open VSCode using `code .` in the current VSCode window?

Whenever I open a new window in VSCode and open up the terminal inside of VSCode and create my project and then use `code .`, it always opens a brand new VSCode window instead of just loading in my current window.

I don't get why it doesn't just load in the current VSCode window instead of opening up a brand new VSCode window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open selected folder in VS Code from the VS Code terminal (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014222/open-selected-folder-in-vs-code-from-the-vs-code-terminal-windows-10)

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options [command line options, including `-r`]

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can achievev this by:

```
code -r .
```

The `-r` flag is the alias for `--reuse-window`.

Moreover, if you experience the same issue on a file basis (e.g., `code test.py` opens `test.py` in the wrong window), you can do:

```
code -r test.py .
```